# Is there any way that I can construct the cross folder route using route-href in Aurelia 1.1.2?

Tags: aurelia

Currently, I have a folder structure as follows:

```
D:.
|   app.html
|   app.js
+---calendars
|       calendar-router.html
|       calendar-router.js
|       details.html
|       details.js
|
+---organizations
|       service.js
|
\---users
        details.html
        details.js
        users-router.html
        users-router.js
```

I would like to create a link **href** in the **calendars/details.html** file to the **users/details.html** file.

```
<a route-href="route: userDetails; params.bind: { id: calendar.owner.id }">details</a>
```

My users-router.js has this entry.

```
 { route: 'details/:id', name: 'userDetails', moduleId: './details', title: 'User details', href: 'details/:id' }
```

But somehow, I'm not able to do so, and get the error **[route-href] Error: A route with name 'userDetails' could not be found. Check that `name: 'userDetails'` was specified in the route's config.**

I tried to inject both the **app.js** and **users-router.js** routers in **calendar/details.js**, and I can see the **AppRouter** is populated but the **UsersRouter** is not.

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: route parameter in route-href should be string. Did you already try it or you only mistyped it in your question?

Comment: @janmvtrinidad, this whole value of route-href is a string.

Comment: Can you post your app.js `routerConfiguration.map` and also the value in url browser when you try to navigate from calendar to user/details?

Comment: @janmvtrinidad here it is. app.js 

`config.map([
      { route: 'users', name: 'users', moduleId: './users/users-router', nav: true, title: 'Users' },
      { route: 'calendars', name: 'calendars', moduleId: './calendars/calendar-router', nav: true, title: 'Calendars' }
    ]);`

Value in the address bar is **http://localhost:9000/#/calendars/details/58f27138a1f59e55e8ca93c2**

Comment: The problem is on the **calendar/details.html** page, it's not able to create a route to the **user/details.html**.

Comment: It seems that by the time you navigate from calendars/details to users/detail, the router is not aware at that time. can you try to navigate to users/detail first. and try to load the child route for it then nabigate to calendar/detail and back again to users/detail. For more info you might find useful this [question](https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/126).

Comment: @janmvtrinidad Aaahaa, actually I'm trying to generate the route on that **calendar/details.html** page, and that's where the error is coming. **[route-href] Error: A route with name 'userDetails' could not be found. Check that name: 'userDetails' was specified in the route's config.**.

As you can see in the question, I'm getting the **AppRouter** but the empty **UserRouter** when gets injected in the **calendar/details.js**.

Comment: I'm sorry, It will help us if you create a gist [here](https://gist.run/).

Comment: Hey @janmvtrinidad, I'll do so, please stay tuned. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the unknown route name is because Aurelia doesn't eagerly load child routers.

The AppRouter within your app.js won't confiure the child router until your users route is navigated to.

The easiest solution is to include the route within your app.js. Then your existing route-href will work.

You can check this issue on github for some additional solutions. https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/90